# What in growisofs the option "-dry-run" does?

Tags: linux, burning, dvd-burning

I've noticed reading the [documentation of growisofs](https://linux.die.net/man/1/growisofs), that there is this option:

> -dry-run
> At dry-run growisofs performs all the steps till, but not including the first write operation. Most notably check for "overburn" condition is performed, which implies that mkisofs is invoked and terminated prematurely.

I supposed two hypothesis: it is a test (burning dvd safely), or it is a simulation without burning. I haven't found much, so I didn't understand it well.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation for `-dry-run` says : "**not including** the first write".

So, yes, this is only a test-run, writing nothing to the DVD.
Its purpose is to check for errors before you
try and ruin a perfectly good DVD.